# How to loop through item in two list in python one by one

Tags: python, for-loop

I was trying to loop through two list which contain two different user, the for loops works when there's item in both list, but it won't works when one of the list doesn't have any item.

```
customer_list = [["ctm1","Jackson","abc"],["ctm2","Kaijun","edf"]]
  admin_list  = [["adm1","Jackson","martinez"],["adm2","Littsen","Lit"]]

for customer,admin in zip(customer_list, admin_list):
     print(customer,admin)
```

No item in admin_list

```
customer_list = [["ctm1","Jackson","abc"],["ctm2","Kaijun","edf"]]
admin_list = []

for customer,admin in zip(customer_list, admin_list):
     print(customer,admin)
```

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: It will be good to have an example code for `but it won't works when one of the list doesn't have any item` and the expected output.

Comment: Just need an if statement for if one of the lists is empty.

Comment: @shahkalpesh I have edited the post and provide the example code, I expected the for loop still able to print(customer)

Comment: An option is to make both lists the same length when you want to use zip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to implement some if’s. Example

```
a=[]

if a:
```

Put after your lists but before your for

Answer (score 2):

Zip function will take the shortest length of array. You need to check null or empty in this case.

Please check reference.
[How to iterate through two lists in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel)

Answer (score 2):

just check if empty or not

```
l1 = [["ctm1","Jackson","abc"],["ctm2","Kaijun","edf"]]
l2 = [["adm1","Jackson","martinez"],["adm2","Littsen","Lit"]]


l3 = zip(l1, l2) if l1 and l2 else l1 if l1 else l2

for x in l3:
    print(x)
```